# Error DataGrid: A field property with the name <variable> was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I'm dealing with a problem when trying to set more than one fields to the DataNavigateUrlField attribute (HyperLinkColumn tag).

I've checked the names of the column in the DataSet, but they are all OK. As a matter of fact, I've been showing those columns inside the DataGrid without any problems.
This is the piece of code from the aspx file:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DtCampana" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Small" Width="640px"
CssClass="estilotabla" Height="40px" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CellSpacing="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="20">
<EditItemStyle Font-Size="XX-Small"></EditItemStyle>
<ItemStyle Font-Size="XX-Small" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
<HeaderStyle Font-Size="XX-Small" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center"
    ForeColor="Black" CssClass="estilocelda"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ROWNUM" HeaderText="N&#176;"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="COD_CAMPANA, NOMBRE_AGREEMENT" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="MantenedorOfertas.aspx?nrocampana={0}&agreement={1}"
            DataTextField="COD_CAMPANA" HeaderText="C&#243;digo campa&ntilde;a"></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DESC_CAMPANA" HeaderText="Descripci&#243;n"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NOMBRE_AGREEMENT" HeaderText="Tipo Agreement"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NOMBRE_CLASS_TIPO" HeaderText="Rubro"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NOMBRE_PRODUCTO" HeaderText="Producto"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DESCRIPCION_TIPO_CAMPANA" HeaderText="Tipo de Oferta"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="STRING_ESTADO" HeaderText="Estado"></asp:BoundColumn>

    </Columns>
<PagerStyle Visible="False" NextPageText="" PrevPageText="" Position="TopAndBottom">
</PagerStyle>
```

When I only use the DataField called "COD_CAMPANA" inside the HyperLinkColumn it works fine, but when I try to add more columns shows the error:
"A field property with the name X was not found on the selected data source."

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong???

Thanks

Comment: The error seems clear to me. The source data does not have one or more columns defined in the GridView (DESC_CAMPANA, NOMBRE_PRODUCTO etc)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the workaround I've used is to change the DataGrid for a GridView and use HyperLinkField. Thanks.